# In this process can occur?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Can I use "in this process can occur" like this?

" The packets are reassembled at the receiver side. Consequently, in this process can  occur, that some packets may be lost and need to be retransmitted or retrieved out of order and need to be reorded"

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Why not simplify? "The packets are reassembled at the receiver side. In this process, some packets may be lost and will need to be retransmitted ..." (And what happens after 'retransmitted' isn't very clear.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't quite correct, the way it is written. It needs to be ***...in this process it can occur that some packets may be lost...***.

Note that I have also removed the comma after occur. I would put one in after *order* further along, to break up what is a quite long sentence.

Comment: 'It can occur that' doesn't seem to be anywhere near as idiomatic as 'It can happen that' according to [these Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=it+can+occur+that%2Cit+can+happen+that&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cit%20can%20occur%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cit%20can%20happen%20that%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I agree. All I did was correct the grammar. But I was tempted to recast the sentence altogether, as you have done.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's unacceptable, and I naughtily didn't mention that 'It transpires that' (which I'd say has intermediate idiomaticity) flatlines on a similar G Ngram search. Perhaps the closeness of 'It occurs to me that ...' weighs against the chioce of 'It occurs that ...'.

Comment: @WS" Thanks for your answer @Edwin thanks for comments. I didnt even know that such website exists :) I love it

Answer (score 0):

Render your version as follows:
Consequently, this process may lead to some packets being lost.